# Where can I download JBoss Developer Studio 2.0 GA?

Tags: java, ide, jboss

I am trying to download JBoss Developer Studio 2.0 GA, but the best I can find on the [SourceForge Downloads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBossIDE) page is [JBossIDE 2.0.0.Beta2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBossIDE/JBossIDE%202.0.0.Beta2). Is there a more recent version that I can download somewhere?

(I don't mind building it from source, although it's not my preferred option.)

Another question is about the file dates. In the [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBossIDE/JBossIDE%202.0.0.Beta2), all files have the date "Wed Oct 11 2006". Is it really *that* old?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that it's now commercial software after RedHat purchased it from Exadel and then rebranded it. I think you can pick it up for $99

http://www.redhat.com/developer_studio/

Comment: I was hoping to find the open-source code somewhere, but you're right, it is only available commercially now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The JBossIDE project was superceded by the JBoss Tools project. The downloads are here: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html

JBoss Developer Studio is a commercially packaged version of JBoss Tools that also integrates a number of other JBoss enterprise technologies and includes certified updates and some level of support from Red Hat. The pricing is subscription based, currently $99 *per year*.

Answer (score -1):

There's a 165Mb download here, I'm guessing it can't all be docs http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.JBDS.GA/

**edit:** Download finished now. Uncompressed, that was 242Mb of docs only. An impressive amount, but it didn't help solving your question I'm afraid :-/

Comment: Geez.why not have some nice videos instead. Who read's those docs?